# Is there a C# equivalent to File.separator in Java

Tags: c#, java

How does C# cope with file separators? Is it always assumed the file separator is "\" (or "\\" and does this have to be escaped like this?

Comment: @all thank you - I had come across a (misleading) article which suggested there was no equivalent

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is what you need. You can find it in the `System.IO` namespace.

Answer (score 16):

To combine paths use, and as suggested by Geo, this works in conjunction with `DirectorySeparatorChar`

```
IO.Path.Combine("path", "file.ext");
```

Answer (score 4):

If by file separators, you really mean directory separators, then you need [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) and [Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx).

These will get the relevant platform-specific characters, without having to hard-code them (and also avoiding the need to escape them properly).